# Why is the firebase security rules not working?

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm using RealTime DataBase for my application, it has security rules:

```
 {
   "rules": {
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
         ".write": "auth.uid != null"
   }
 }
```

This is the code snippet where the data is getting:

```
func firstLaunchCataloguePartsFetchData(
        result : @escaping((Result<[CatalogueParts], Error>) -> Void)
    ) {
        if ConnectionManager.shared.isConnected {
            let baseUrl = Constants.baseUrl + DirectoryType.catalogueParts.addJsonAbbreviation
            guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl ) else { return }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    result(.failure(error))
                } else if let data = data,
                          let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
                          let downloadedMarks = Mapper<CatalogueParts>().mapArray(JSONString: jsonString) {
                    result(.success(downloadedMarks))
                } else {
                    result(.success([]))
                }
            }
            .resume()
        } else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "Connection error detected", code: 911, userInfo: nil)
            result(.failure(error))
        }
    }
```

Here I am using the received data to draw a table view:

```
func getFirstLaunchCatalogueParts() {
        ShopManager.shared.firstLaunchCataloguePartsFetchData { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let catalogueParts):
                self.catalogueParts = catalogueParts
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            case .failure(let error as NSError):
                self.showErrorAlert(error: error, withAction: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Even if I'm authorized, passed phone authorization (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid has somevalue) - i can't display the tableView, received data is nil

But!
This works great, the table is rendered, everything works if the rules are made like this:

```
{
   "rules": {
         ".read": "true",
         ".write": "auth.uid != null"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Security rules don't do anything until you actually try to access the database. Please edit your question to show the minimal code fragment that also reads/writes data and that is failing. In that code, it typically helps if you log the UID of the user right before accessing the database, to prove to yourself that you are indeed meeting the conditions of your rules.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected and added my question

Comment: Thanks for that update. Unfortunately I don't immediately see any calls to the Firebase API in there, which makes it hard to say what's going on. Can you show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can copy/paste/run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (read the link please, as it contains lots of guidance that increases the chances we can effectively help)

Comment: Thanks! I started to prepare a minimal code and suddenly, probably, I understood what the problem was. I indicated this in the answer, your opinion is very interesting

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @AlexM! And Thanks for sharing your solution.  --- Finding the problem yourself is actually quite common when creating a minimal repro, and it's one of the reasons we so often ask for them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the problem was this:

I was accessing Firebase using this method, it is not the basic method of reading firebase service data

```
let baseUrl = Constants.baseUrl + ".JSON"
// where baseUrl is just http path to my database and if you add ".JSON" to it - you 
// open the contents of the database in Json
guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl ) else { return }
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
```

Then I used the given Data to parse through the model:

```
let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
let downloadedDataAsModel = Mapper<CatalogueParts>().mapArray(JSONString: jsonString)
```

The problem is that using this method, regardless of the rules - you get the data in any case, while the ObjectMapper processes and creates an instance, but it is incomplete, and no error occurs here

```
let downloadedDataAsModel = Mapper<CatalogueParts>().mapArray (JSONString: jsonString)
```

Therefore, this method does not allow rule settings other than "read : true"

I tried using this method and everything really worked - depending on the authorized status, access was allowed or restricted. Now it remains to decide how to use this method to get data in the form of Json for further processing =)

```
func fetchData(){
        let ref = Constants.ref
        ref.child("CatalogueParts").getData { error, snapshot in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return;
              }
            let someValue = snapshot.value
            print(someValue)
        }
    }
```